# Submenu positioning issues

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Here's what I'm working with currently, I'm trying to create a drop down menu for the team section but it keeps showing up to the left of the menu selection for teams. Here the site for reference:

http://lakenonabaseballassociation.com/

CSS

```
.header 
{
    background: none ;
    height: 50px;
    width:960px;
    margin: auto auto;
    padding: 25px 0 0 33px;
}
.header ul 
    {
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
        margin:0;
        overflow:hidden;
        padding:9px 9px 0 0;
    }
    .header ul li 
        {
            float:left;
        }
    .header ul li a 
        {
            color:#656465;
            font-family:bevanregular;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:400;
            letter-spacing:.025em;
            line-height:30px;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            margin: 175px 11px 0 11px;
        }
    .header ul li.selected a, .header ul li a:hover 
        {
            color:#026593;
        }
```

With this as a basic menu

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="/">Home</a>|
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/teams">Teams</a>|
    <!--<ul>
     <li><a href="#">8U</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">9U</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">10U</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">11U</a></li>
  </ul>-->
        </li>
<li>
    <a href="/schedule">Schedule</a>|
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/forms">Forms</a>|
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/sponsors">Sponsors</a>|
</li>
<!--
<li>
    <a href="/news">News</a>|
</li>
-->
<!--
<li>
    <a href="/media">Media</a>|
</li>
-->
<li>
    <a href="/about-us">About</a>|
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/contact-us">Contact</a>
</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
```

If I change the position in CSS to relative it will move it from where it is to the left of the image. Center position will shift the contact link over the logo. I'm guess I'm missing some extra coding in the CSS for the submenu but I've tried a few things and they don't seem to work. Any assistance in getting this functional would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this the full HTML and CSS to your menu?

Comment: you can try something like this...http://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/s5qoy4t4/  

or provide full code

Comment: The code you've posted seems to be for the top level menu - there is no styling for the dropdown menu. Can you post some code or a JSFiddle or CodePen demo showing what you've tried to get the dropdown working?

Comment: The dropdown is commented out.

Comment: You need to lookup some more information on positioning. First off, there's no such thing as ``center`` position. Your list item -- the parent of your dropdown -- needs to be position relative. Your unordered list -- the dropdown itself -- needs to be position absolute. And don't make the list items in your dropdown ``float:left`` unless you want your menu items all on one line, which I would guess you probably don't. Also, you need to remove ``overflow:hidden`` on your unordered list.

Comment: @Jeff The markup for the dropdown is commented out, yes, but there are no CSS styles specifically targeting it (e.g. .header ul ul {}) so it seems to me there are some CSS styles missing. As far as I can tell the styles that have been posted are for the top level menu, not the dropdown.

Comment: I inherited this page from someone else, I'm going in blind. As for the questions. dropdown is commented out for now because the site is live, so I don't want that code working until I fix the issue.

The menu was very basic but now they want drop downs all the coding for the basic menu was being handle in the header section of the code. There's no addition coding in the CSS for menus. 

Is guess the biggest question is should add to the current header code in CSS or basically create from scratch a style that can do dropdowns?

Comment: @JonathanNicol you're right. I was looking at Soup's example page.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, the code you've posted does not contain any styling for the dropdown menu. Here's a fiddle showing how you could go about creating a CSS-only dropdown menu based on your existing markup and styles:

http://jsfiddle.net/w3khgygb/2/

```
.header ul {
    overflow: visible;
}
.header ul li {
    position: relative;
}

/* Dropdown */
 .header ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background: #ddd;
}
.header ul ul li {
    float: none;
}
.header > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Please note that the top level `ul` on your site currently has `overflow` set to `hidden`, which will hide any dropdown menu. As you can see I have changed the overflow to `visible`.

Comment: That's basically what I need thanks @JonathanNicol! Only issue is when I put what you did in fiddle in the style the menu stays where it belongs but it shifts the content of the body over to the right and squishes it.

Comment: I can't answer that without seeing a demo of the issue.